# Disable dates in dynamically created datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker in my form and I just initialized bootstrap datepicker in an input field which created dynamically. The code snippet is

```
$('.editTableDatePicker').datepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    minDate: '02/19/2015',
    maxDate: '02/22/2015'
});
```

It shows date picker only. It doesn't disable the dates. I've tried

```
$('.editTableDatePicker').datepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    startDate: '02/19/2015', // also tried setStartDate
    endDate: '02/22/2015' // also tried setEndDate
});
```

What I'm trying to do is to show only dates within a range. For example, from 02/19/2015 to 02/23/2015. Can someone help me?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors are there..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.editTableDatePicker').datepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    startDate: '02/19/2015',
    endDate: '02/22/2015',
});
```

Use `startDate` and `endDate` instead of `minDate/maxDate`

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/options.html

Comment: what is difference between this and OP second attempt? `Try this` doesn't explain anything

Comment: @charlietfl: we need to use startDate/endDate instead of minDate/maxDate

Comment: @ling.s : Just once double check requirements:
    Bootstrap 2.0.4+ , jQuery 1.7.1+ or any other js/css files

Comment: Yes.. fine. It is not working because of I just created the input dynamically I think

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra comma at the end of your object, try this:

```
$('.editTableDatePicker').datepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    startDate: '02/19/2015',
    endDate: '02/22/2015' // No comma here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    startDate: '02/13/2015',
    endDate: '02/22/2015' 
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/B4BzK/239/)

Answer (score 0):

Insted of **minDate/maxDate** use **startDate/endDate**

```
  $('.editTableDatePicker').datepicker({
format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
startDate: '02/19/2015',
endDate: '02/22/2015',
```

});